# Door closer for a door that is not leveled to the wall.

Tags: doors

I would like to put a door closer in a door. The problem is that the door is not like a normal door as the one below:
[image]

the door has no walls to its side or above it. It's like a door in the middle of a tunnel. Like this:
[image]

Because of this I can't use a normal door closer like the one in the first drawing. Do you guys know of any door closer that can be used in a door installed like this?

Comment: This could be a duplicate, yes. Interestingly, the solutions provided at the linked question are unlikely to provide the answer needed in this case. Some of them are quite complex mechanisms. I'm glad I didn't find those in my research!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have normal or near normal hinges, you may be able to use a hinge mounted door closer. They exist in many forms, with published ratings for doors weighing from 30 pounds to as much as 150 pounds.

One model does not require a hinge installation and appears to be mountable on the door frame.

[image: door closer]

The photo shows the heavy capacity version. This particular unit is found on [Amazon (US)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003DQGEMQ) for a rather reasonable price, considering the capacity is listed at 150 pounds.

The above site also shows an installation video of about four minutes. Disregarding editing, it seems likely one could install this closer in four minutes.

Adjustable tension, various colors, seems like a great product.

If this doesn't meet your requirements, the search terms "hinge mounted door closer" should find something that will.

Comment: In all the videos that use the closer in the picture, it's placed in the same plane of the door (in the door frame, or next to it in the wall). But in my case I have no frame at all and no space to place it in the same plane. Do you think if place it in the wall making 90 degrees  with the door it will work?

Comment: I think that it will work in the manner you describe because it has the series of holes on the spring disk that allow different placement of rotation. If you consider that "in the same plane" and 90° turning would be identical if you can place the entire unit at the same distance from the door plane, the spring disk does not know the difference.